# Codeigniter try to load a language file while there is an error reporting

Tags: php, codeigniter

When sql is wrong, CI try to load a db_lang.php file, and I can't see the original error reporting. When there are other errors, it try to load another XXX_lang.php file. How to fix the bug?

It just print an error "Unable to load the request XXX_lang.php bahlahbahlah...."